# In Rails app, jQuery click handler stops working after clicking link to go back

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a page `function_a.html.erb` to display some images. I defined a class `liimg` and call a jQuery to detect a click event on an image.

Everything is fine and when an image is clicked I have the desired page `function_b.html.erb` displayed.

The problem occurs when I go back to the `function_a` page with `<%= link_to 'back', :back %>` – after this, the click on images is no longer detectable.

Am I missing something? But what? Help is welcome.

Comment: Could you please add some code ? 
Show your jQuery code

Comment: Maybe Turbolinks is the problem. Try disabling it and see if it still happens. You might also try to write your click event handler using `delegate` instead of `on`. See http://api.jquery.com/delegate/